# Checking if it exists in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, random

I have this script to generate a random number, but I need it to be unique. I have tried to do it with a `while` loop and check if it already exists in the database but it doesn't work for me.

```
 $numbers = range(6, 1);
    $random = '';
    shuffle($numbers);
    foreach ($numbers as $number) {
        $random.= $number;
    }
```

This is the code I tried to work with

```
    var stop_cycle = 0;

while (!stop_cycle) {
$numbers = range(6, 1);
    $random = '';
    shuffle($numbers);
    foreach ($numbers as $number) {
        $random.= $number;
    }
$db->query("SELECT upload_ID FROM uploads WHERE upload_ID = ".$random);

// check if query returns any result
if(mysql_affected_rows() == 0)  {

// DOING STUFF

// end cycle
 stop_cycle=1;
}

}
```

Comment: Care to share what you've tried that didn't work? Could be a hidden gem!

Comment: Show us the code which doesn't work and not the code which works.

Comment: your foreach is pointless. `$random = implode('', $numbers)` would do just as well.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and don't add code/information in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. The problem is that you can't generate a new number unless the page has been refreshed. I've created a function that the script can keep calling until it has found a database entry with no results.

```
<?php
function generateNumber(){
$numbers = range(6, 1);
$random = '';
shuffle($numbers);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    $random.= $number;
}
return $random;
}

// start the do loop. If the query returns more than 0 results, it will 
// pick up another number and attempt again.
do { 
    $number = generateNumber();
    $mysqli->query("SELECT upload_ID FROM uploads WHERE upload_ID = $number");
}while(mysqli_num_rows > 0);

?>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: No problem, I'll start to explain it - Edit incoming!

Comment: What happens if you comment out the do loop and call the function?

Comment: So PHP doesn't like do { } while loop

Comment: It may be my problem, please change line: `$number = $random; ` too `$number = generateNumber();`

Comment: I've also updated the doloop to something a little cleaner